# How do i stop the script executing at .then phase in fetch?

Tags: javascript, fetch

How do i stop the script executing at .then phase in fetch? I want the script to stop executing if the response and response.text is not empty

```
fetch(url, {
  method: 'POST',
  body: data,
  credentials: 'include',
  })
  .then(response => response.text())
  .then(html => {
    if (html && html.length) {
      $('#modal-content').html('');
      $('#modal-content').append(html);
     //STOP here.
    }
  })
  .then(({ status }) => {
    if (status === 200) {
      document.location.reload(true);
    } 
  })
```

UPD: I ended up writing another if condition to

```
  if (status === 200 && $('#notavailable-modal').length == 0) {
      document.location.reload(true);
    }
```

Comment: Why do you need the last `.then` at all? Why not move that logic into the previous callback?

Comment: Because i dont want to reload if response is not empty

Comment: If the update answers your question it's better you post it as an actual answer and mark your question answered.

Comment: the update solves my problem, but it does not answer the question

Answer (score 0):

```
 throw "Stop!";
```

You could reject the returned promise, then further `.then` handlers wouldn't be executed.

Or you just merge the two `.then`s into one:

```
if (html && html.length) {
  $('#modal-content').html('');
  $('#modal-content').append(html);
  // no need to STOP here
} else if (status === 200) {
  document.location.reload(true);
}
```

Comment: The thing is i literally want to stop at the place i mentioned,